# testng.xml report is not executing all test cases in test suite

Tags: testng

I am trying to run my TestNG suite with  testng.xml. I have total four classes in my suite but I am only able to run two classes at a time with all methods. Suppose I have 3 methods in each class, so in TestNG suite if I add only two classes, testng.xml file will run my both tests with 6 methods. Now if I try to add 3rd class in my testng.xml file, it will run only first method from each class. it means now it is running only 3 methods( one from each class).I have created a source folder under my project and then created this testng.xml file inside this source folder.  Would you please let me know what I am doing wrong. Below is my testng.xml file and test cases.

[image]

testng.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="MurcuryTour AUtomation suite"> 
<test name="MurcuryTour">
 <classes>
        <class name="murcuryTourPagesTests.LoginPageTest"></class>
        <class name="murcuryTourPagesTests.FlightsPageTest"></class>
        <class name="murcuryTourPagesTests.HomePageTest"></class>

</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Please share the Test Class code as well. On Side note have you tried to delete this XML and re-create a new one ?

Comment: Following are the three classes that I am trying to run in test suite.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my all test classes that I am trying to run in test suite.
package murcuryTourPagesTests;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.pages.FlightsPage;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.pages.LoginPage;

public class LoginPageTest extends TestBase{
    LoginPage loginpage;
    FlightsPage flightspage;

    public LoginPageTest() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeClass
        public void setup() {
        initialization();
        loginpage = new LoginPage();
        flightspage = new FlightsPage();
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
        public void titleVerification() {
        String title =loginpage.validatePageTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(title,"Sign-on: Mercury Tours");
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void login() {
        flightspage =loginpage.login(prop.getProperty       ("username"),prop.getProperty("password"));

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
    }

 }


    -----------------------------------------------------------
2nd class:

package murcuryTourPagesTests;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.pages.LoginPage;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.pages.RegistrationPage;

public class HomePageTest extends TestBase {
    LoginPage loginpage;
    HomePage homepage;
    RegistrationPage registrationPage;

    public HomePageTest() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
    initialization();
    loginpage = new LoginPage();
    loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"),prop.getProperty("password"));
    homepage = new HomePage();
    registrationPage = new RegistrationPage();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void click_On_Home_Tab() {
    homepage.Click_On_Home_Tab();
      }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void home_Page_Title_Verification() {
    String title = homepage.Verify_HomePage_Title();
    Assert.assertEquals(title, "Welcome: Mercury Tours");

    }

    @AfterSuite

    public void tearDown() {
    driver.close();
    }

    }

---------------------------------------------------------------------

3rd class:

package murcuryTourPagesTests;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.pages.FlightsPage;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.MurcuryTour.qa.pages.LoginPage;

public class FlightsPageTest extends TestBase{

    LoginPage loginpage;
    FlightsPage flightspage;
    HomePage homepage;

    public FlightsPageTest() {
        super();
    }


    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
    initialization();
    loginpage= new LoginPage();
    loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"),prop.getProperty   ("password"));
    flightspage= new FlightsPage();
    homepage= new HomePage();
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void verifyFlightsPageTitle() {

    String title =flightspage.varifyFlightsPageTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(title,"Find a Flight: Mercury Tours:");

    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void move_To_Find_A_FlightPage() {

    flightspage.clickOnFindFlights();   

    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void move_To_Reservation_Page(){
        flightspage.clickOnreserveFlights();

    }

    @Test(priority=4)
    public void enter_User_Inofrmation() {
        flightspage.enterUserInformation();
    }

    @Test(priority=5)
    public void back_To_Home_Page(){
        homepage=flightspage.backToHomePage();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
    }


}
```